# Data lost after a while of adding it in Dialogflow Is it a storage or server problem?

Tags: dialogflow-es, stability

We are working on Dialogflow for a year now, and lately, we experienced some issues regarding stabilization, new behavior and new features causing problems. Among those problems is that when adding a synonym to an entity or a training phrases and hit save, wait for it to train then refresh again, all the newly added items are gone. It seems that Dialogflow is experiencing storage issues. And we are losing time trying to retrain again and add those items again and this is frustrating.

We have tried to troubleshoot this issue for more than a week and it seems that those issues still there:

*Example 1*: Synonyms already exist but Dialogflow treats them like they don't exist when visiting the "Validation" option.

*Example 2*: Adding new synonyms, saving and training; After a while, they disappear.

*Example 3*: The DF server is most of the time unavailable.

Please, **Dialogflow Support Team** helps us check those issues.

Thank you.

Comment: have you clear cache and then try?

Comment: Hello, is it possible to clear the cache on Dialogflow? if yes please show me how!! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

If you are an Enterprise customer I would suggest to contact them directly, if not probably you should switch to enterprise for better customer support. Since you have been using DF for a year now, you guys might have reaches some limits. For example, a single agent cannot have more than 1 million entity reference values and synonyms. For more information on quotas and limits check the following link: [Doc](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas)

Comment: Hello, Thank you for your answer but here I am talking about the instability of Dialogflow in itself( we make a change today, tomorrow it's deleted). And we already did a benchmarking and we are sure we didn't reach the limited Quota. Actually, we are using one intent and 5 entities. We are getting a lot of warnings in the validation beta section. And we detected some behavior changes with Dialigflow. That's why we are asking the Dialogflow Support Team to fill us with updates if possible and we've been redirected directly to ask them here.

Comment: I see, hope they will see your question. I would suggest to post it in FB community. It's more active in there